# Dilemma of Const type in C++

Tags: c++, insert, constants, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement BST in c++ using recursion. However, I found myself in dilemma.

In the **Insert function**, I use reference `TreeNode *&node`to pass the function argument. I don't want make the reference const, because I need change node in Insert function. On the other side, when I call function like `tree.Insert(10, tree.Getroot())`, it occurs error because function `Getroot` creates temporary variable which can't not be assigned to non-const reference. And I know I can easily fix it by making the `TreeNode *root`public, but I don't want do that.

What should I do to fix it or is there any better design? Please help, thanks in advance.
Here's the head file.

```
#ifndef BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H
#define BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_H

class TreeNode
{
public:
  TreeNode(int x = 0,TreeNode* l = nullptr, TreeNode* r = nullptr)
  : element(x), left(l), right(r) { }

  int element;
  TreeNode* left;
  TreeNode* right;
};


class BST
{
public:
  BST(TreeNode *t = nullptr) : root(t) {}

  void Insert(int x, TreeNode*& node)
  {
    if (node == nullptr) {
      node = new TreeNode(x, nullptr, nullptr);
      if (node == nullptr)
        std::cout << "Insert Failure" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (node->element < x) {
      Insert(x, node->right); //easy to make a mistake
    }
    else if (node->element > x) {
      Insert(x, node->left);
    }
  }

  TreeNode *Getroot()
  {
    return root;
  }

private:
  TreeNode* root;
};

#endif
```

Comment: The tree shouldn't expose its node type in the public interface - make it private to the tree. The public function should be `void Insert(int x);` and `GetRoot` shouldn't exist at all. Once you hide the implementation details, many problems disappear.

Comment: You probably know your Insert does not insert anything if the pointer is a nullptr. Please rethink your design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement Insert at a node level as well as tree level. Then the insert logic should either be handled at the root level by the tree or at depth by the node you're inserting at. I have an example tree implemented [here](https://github.com/kdinev/DataStructures/blob/master/Tree/TreeADT.h). It might not be the best implementation but maybe it will be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you. Your implementation is really helpful.

Comment: I found a better version of BST.http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson18.html

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef __BINARYTREENODE__
#define __BINARYTREENODE__

class BinaryTreeNode {

public:
    BinaryTreeNode(int);
    int element;
    BinaryTreeNode *left;
    BinaryTreeNode *right;
};

#endif /* __BINARYTREENODE__ */


    #ifndef __BINARYSEARCHTREE__
    #define __BINARYSEARCHTREE__

    #include "BinaryTreeNode.h"

    using namespace std;

    class BinarySearchTree {

    public:
        BinarySearchTree();
        ~BinarySearchTree();
        void insert(int);

    private:
        BinaryTreeNode *root;
        void insert(int, BinaryTreeNode * & n);

    };

    #endif /* __BINARYSEARCHTREE__ */


#include "BinarySearchTree.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

BinarySearchTree::BinarySearchTree(){}

void BinarySearchTree::insert(int element)
{
    insert(element, this->root);
}
void BinarySearchTree::insert(int element, BinaryTreeNode* & n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        n = new BinaryTreeNode(element);
    }
    else if (n->element > element)
    {
        insert(element, n->left);
    }
    else if (n->element < element)
    {
        insert(element, n->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not only copy-paste code as an answer. Some explanation would be needed, too.